# How to remove unwanted characters from Pandas Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a multi-index full of a mix of ascii characters and Japanese characters.
How can efficiently remove unwanted Japanese from the string column labels in all levels of the multi index?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved using regex and unicode ranges for japanese characters:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

col_list=[]
            for tuple in df.columns:
                new_tuple = (
                    re.sub(r"[\u3000\u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]", "", tuple[0]),
                    re.sub(r"[\u3000\u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]", "", tuple[1])
                    )
                col_list.append(new_tuple)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col_list)
```